# CSRF issue on TemplateView

Tags: django, csrf

I have a extremely simple django TemplateView as follow:

```
class Homeview(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home.html'
```

And i have csrfmiddleware enabled, but why the CSRF cookie is not set on that home view? I have form rely on the csrf cookie on that page. I do not want to use `{% csrf_token %}` tag to do this.

I tried debug this, and found the cookie was never set because it failed the condition of `CSRF_COOKIE_USED`, this variable does not exist in my `request.META`.

```
def process_response(self, request, response):
        if getattr(response, 'csrf_processing_done', False):
            return response

        # If CSRF_COOKIE is unset, then CsrfViewMiddleware.process_view was
        # never called, probaby because a request middleware returned a response
        # (for example, contrib.auth redirecting to a login page).
        if request.META.get("CSRF_COOKIE") is None:
            return response

        if not request.META.get("CSRF_COOKIE_USED", False):
            return response      # **It returned here, so COOKIE is never set!**

        # Set the CSRF cookie even if it's already set, so we renew
        # the expiry timer.
        response.set_cookie(settings.CSRF_COOKIE_NAME,
                            request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"],
                            max_age = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 52,
                            domain=settings.CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN,
                            path=settings.CSRF_COOKIE_PATH,
                            secure=settings.CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE
                            )
        # Content varies with the CSRF cookie, so set the Vary header.
        patch_vary_headers(response, ('Cookie',))
        response.csrf_processing_done = True
        return response
```

Append my context processor settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
)
```

Also finding something very strange:

the csrf_cookie exists if {% csrf_token %} presents in my template.

Comment: `"I do not want to use {% csrf_token %} tag to do this."` why not?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I have written a generic javascript widget which supposed to handle all csrf issues, it relies on the csrf cookie is set.

Comment: If you are on 1.4, use [`ensure_csrf_cookie`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie), otherwise use [`this javascript snippet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax). Best not to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I think you answered question, ensure_csrf_cookie is the way to go, I thought that django forces csrf_cookie is always set for all HTTP request through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on 1.4, use [`ensure_csrf_cookie`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie), otherwise use this [javascript snippet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax).